# Generate incrementing number based on prefix

Tags: sql-server

I've got a database table with a number of columns, including a Guid primary key. This works fine, and I can't change it.

I need to generate a "friendly" string identifier with a known prefix and an incrementing padded number.

For example, I have these rows, and I need to create the FriendlyID column.

```
ID                                   | Prefix   | FriendlyID
(PK, uniqueidentifier)               |(nvarchar)| 
-------------------------------------|----------|------------ 
93AE63F0-4556-426A-B61D-A86D66DCD904 | AB       | AB0001        
191D1186-1C4D-4A6C-A83B-D803BFAA2DF1 | AB       | AB0002
F28CA0D0-4ED9-4F89-9467-F7C2B7DFDCEE | BC       | BC0001
9DACD157-FF51-447B-BDD6-6A82E3E45758 | DE       | DE0001
AF3952B8-2E28-4D85-85C8-473DA64D6BDB | BC       | BC0002
9DACD157-FF51-447B-BDD6-6A82E3E45758 | AB       | AB0003
```

The number needs to increment, but only based on the prefix.

I know how to create an autoincrementing integer column, but I'm not sure how to make it increment within the prefix.

If it's easier, I could definitely build the FriendlyID for display (e.g. concatenating the prefix and number), but I want the database to handle generating the numeric portion to make sure that we don't end up with collisions. If it matters, that would be in C#/Entity Framework Core 5.

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: What's wrong with `ROW_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 1):

You may number the rows using `ROW_NUMBER()` and the appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   CONCAT(
      Prefix, 
      RIGHT(CONCAT('0000', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Prefix ORDER BY ID)), 4)
   ) AS FriendlyID
FROM (VALUES
   ('93AE63F0-4556-426A-B61D-A86D66DCD904', 'AB'),        
   ('191D1186-1C4D-4A6C-A83B-D803BFAA2DF1', 'AB'),
   ('F28CA0D0-4ED9-4F89-9467-F7C2B7DFDCEE', 'BC'),
   ('9DACD157-FF51-447B-BDD6-6A82E3E45758', 'DE'),
   ('AF3952B8-2E28-4D85-85C8-473DA64D6BDB', 'BC'),
   ('9DACD157-FF51-447B-BDD6-6A82E3E45758', 'AB')
) v (ID, Prefix)
```